# Simplify two MySQL queries to one by join and/or union

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, union

I have two queries:

```
(SELECT b904_Vasarlas.PrintedFigure as Image, 
    b904_Vasarlas.ProductColor as Color, 
    SUM(b904_Vasarlas.QTY) as QTY 
FROM `b904_Vasarlas` 
GROUP BY 1, 2) 
ORDER by 1, 2
```

With good output:

```
Image;Color;QTY
"villamos","blue","5"
"villamos","pink","5"
"virag","blue","5"
"virag","pink","5"
"virag2","blue","5"
"virag2","pink","5"
"vitorlas","blue","5"
"vitorlas","pink","5"
"vonat","blue","5"
"vonat","pink","5"
"zaszlo","blue","5"
"zaszlo","pink","5"
"zsiraf","blue","15"
"zsiraf","pink","15"
```

and

```
(SELECT b904_Eladas.PrintedFigure as Image, 
    b904_Eladas.ProductColor as Color, 
    SUM(b904_Eladas.QTY) as QTY 
FROM `b904_Eladas` 
GROUP BY 1, 2) 
ORDER by 1, 2
```

With good output:

```
Image;Color;QTY
"golya","blue","20"
"golya","pink","10"
"hajokormany","blue","20"
"hajokormany","pink","10"
"macska","blue","10"
"macska","pink","10"
"malac","blue","10"
"malac","pink","10"
"villamos","blue","3"
"villamos","pink","3"
"virag","blue","3"
"virag","pink","3"
"virag2","blue","4"
"vitorlas","blue","5"
"vitorlas","pink","5"
"vonat","blue","5"
"vonat","pink","5"
"zaszlo","blue","15"
"zaszlo","pink","5"
"zsiraf","blue","16"
"zsiraf","pink","11"
```

How can I get the difference of QTY columns of two tables with only one mysql query grouped by Image AND color columns?

---

Finally I used this longer code, But I think I can solve the problem with only one query string more simple.

```
$Eladasok = array();
$ElLoop = 0;
$GyartasQuery = '(SELECT ' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Vasarlas.PrintedFigure as RaktarKep, ' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Vasarlas.ProductColor as RaktarSzin, SUM(' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Vasarlas.QTY) as RaktarQTY  FROM `' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Vasarlas` GROUP BY 1, 2) ORDER by 1, 2';
$EladasQuery = '(SELECT ' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Eladas.PrintedFigure as EladasKep, ' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Eladas.ProductColor as EladasSzin, SUM(' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Eladas.QTY) as EladasQTY  FROM `' . $DBConnection[1] . '_Eladas` GROUP BY 1, 2) ORDER by 1, 2';
$GyartasResult = mysql_query($GyartasQuery);
$EladasResult = mysql_query($EladasQuery);

while(false !== $EladasContent = mysql_fetch_assoc($EladasResult)) {                        
    $new_array[] = $EladasContent;
    $Eladasok[$new_array[$ElLoop][EladasKep] . '-' . $new_array[$ElLoop][EladasSzin]] = $EladasContent[EladasQTY];
    $ElLoop++;
}

while(false !== $GyartasContent = mysql_fetch_assoc($GyartasResult)) {
    if (($GyartasContent[RaktarQTY] - $Eladasok[$GyartasContent[RaktarKep] . '-' . $GyartasContent[RaktarSzin]]) <= 0) {
        $Cellcolour = ' bgcolor="#DDDDDD"';
        $CellHighlight = ' bgcolor="#FFBBBB"';
    } else {
        $Cellcolour = '';
        $CellHighlight = '';
    }

    echo'
    <tr><td align=center' . $CellHighlight . '>'.++$RoNo.'</td>
    <td' . $Cellcolour . '>' . $GyartasContent[RaktarKep] . ' - ' . $GyartasContent[RaktarSzin] .  '</td>
    <td' . $Cellcolour . '>' . intval($GyartasContent[RaktarQTY]) . '</td>
    <td' . $Cellcolour . '>' . intval($Eladasok[$GyartasContent[RaktarKep] . '-' . $GyartasContent[RaktarSzin]]) . '</td>
    <td' . $Cellcolour . '>' .  intval($GyartasContent[RaktarQTY] - $Eladasok[$GyartasContent[RaktarKep] . '-' . $GyartasContent[RaktarSzin]]). 
    '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tr></table></div>';
```

Comment: Can you load your data (or at least a sample) into sqlfiddle.com so that code can be tested?

Comment: I tested the code by PHPMyadmin. Working, but the sum(column) is wrong after groupping. I have same problem with my own query.

Comment: Here is the link for testing with my own code but with wrong summarized column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b238/2

Comment: I am not sure that the problem can be solved with only one query... The solution would be very good to order results by columns.

Answer (score 0):

The content of database1:

SELECT `PrintedFigure`, `ProductColor`, `QTY` FROM `b904_vasarlas`

```
(Name, color, QTY)
"villamos","blue","5"
"villamos","pink","5"
"virÃ¡g","blue","5"
"virÃ¡g","pink","5"
"virÃ¡g2","blue","5"
"virÃ¡g2","pink","5"
"vitorlÃ¡s","blue","5"
"vitorlÃ¡s","pink","5"
"vonat","blue","5"
"vonat","pink","5"
"zsirÃ¡f","blue","5"
"zsirÃ¡f","pink","5"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","blue","5"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","pink","5"
"zsirÃ¡f","blue","10"
"zsirÃ¡f","pink","10"
```

The content of database2:

SELECT `PrintedFigure`, `ProductColor`, `QTY` FROM `b904_eladas`

```
(Name, color, QTY)
"vitorlÃ¡s","blue","5"
"vitorlÃ¡s","pink","5"
"vonat","blue","5"
"vonat","pink","5"
"zsirÃ¡f","blue","5"
"zsirÃ¡f","pink","5"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","blue","5"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","pink","5"
"zsirÃ¡f","blue","5"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","blue","10"
"zsirÃ¡f","blue","6"
"zsirÃ¡f","pink","6"
"gÃ³lya","blue","10"
"gÃ³lya","pink","10"
"hajÃ³kormÃ¡ny","blue","10"
"hajÃ³kormÃ¡ny","pink","10"
"macska","blue","10"
"macska","pink","10"
"malac","blue","10"
"malac","pink","10"
"villamos","blue","3"
"villamos","pink","3"
"virÃ¡g","blue","3"
"virÃ¡g","pink","3"
"virÃ¡g2","blue","4"
"gÃ³lya","blue","10"
"hajÃ³kormÃ¡ny","blue","10"
```

I need the difference of column called QTY when PrintedFigure AND the product color is same in booth databases.

Your result is wrong:

```
Image,Color,QtyV,QtyE,Qty,QtyOtherWay 
"gÃ³lya","blue","0","0","-20","-20"
"gÃ³lya","pink","0","0","-10","-10"
"hajÃ³kormÃ¡ny","blue","0","0","-20","-20"
"hajÃ³kormÃ¡ny","pink","0","0","-10","-10"
"macska","blue","0","0","-10","-10"
"macska","pink","0","0","-10","-10"
"malac","blue","0","0","-10","-10"
"malac","pink","0","0","-10","-10"
"villamos","blue","5","5","2","2"
"villamos","pink","5","5","2","2"
"virÃ¡g","blue","5","5","2","2"
"virÃ¡g","pink","5","5","2","2"
"virÃ¡g2","blue","5","5","1","1"
"virÃ¡g2","pink","5","5","5","5"
"vitorlÃ¡s","blue","5","5","0","0"
"vitorlÃ¡s","pink","5","5","0","0"
"vonat","blue","5","5","0","0"
"vonat","pink","5","5","0","0"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","blue","10","10","-5","-5"
"zÃ¡szlÃ³","pink","5","5","0","0"
"zsirÃ¡f","blue","45","45","13","13"
"zsirÃ¡f","pink","30","30","8","8"
```

I have exactly same problem before when I tried using join and union.

The result is good with code using two queries and while loop for array creation:

```
#   Name and color      Difference
1   villamos - blue     2
2   villamos - pink     2
3   virág - blue        2
4   virág - pink        2
5   virág2 - blue       1
6   virág2 - pink       5
7   vitorlás - blue     0
8   vitorlás - pink     0
9   vonat - blue        0
10  vonat - pink        0
11  zászló - blue       -10
12  zászló - pink       0
13  zsiráf - blue       -1
14  zsiráf - pink       4
```

I am asking the solution of one query because I want to cancel using this loop:

```
            while(false !== $EladasContent = mysql_fetch_assoc($EladasResult)) {                        
                $new_array[] = $EladasContent;
                $Eladasok[$new_array[$ElLoop][EladasKep] . '-' . $new_array[$ElLoop][EladasSzin]] = $EladasContent[EladasQTY];
                $ElLoop++;
            }
```

Comment: The problem the wrong result in the summarized QTY columns when the another database contains rows with same name/color compinations. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand...Sorry about that.  Below are two solutions (I believe the first one is better for performance, but not positive)  In either case, the zsiraf+pink is 15 & 11 with a difference of 4

```
SELECT MasterList.Name, MasterList.Color, E.EQty, V.VQty
, COALESCE(V.VQty, 0) - COALESCE(E.EQty,0) AS NetQty
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Name, Color
FROM b904_Eladas
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Color
FROM b904_Vasarlas) AS MasterList
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Name,Color, SUM(QTY) AS EQty
  FROM b904_Eladas 
  GROUP BY Name,Color
 )AS E
ON MasterList.Name = E.Name AND MasterList.Color = E.Color
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Name,Color, SUM(QTY) AS VQty
  FROM b904_Vasarlas 
  GROUP BY Name,Color
 )AS V
ON MasterList.Name = V.Name AND MasterList.Color = V.Color
ORDER BY 1,2
```

---

```
SELECT 
E.Name AS EName
, V.Name AS VName
, COALESCE(E.Name ,v.Name) AS Name
, E.Color AS EColor
, V.Color AS VColor
, COALESCE(E.Color , V.Color) AS Color
, COALESCE(E.Total_QTY,0) AS EQTY
, COALESCE(V.Total_QTY, 0) AS VQTY
, COALESCE(V.Total_QTY,0) - COALESCE(E.Total_QTY, 0) AS NETQTY
FROM
  (SELECT b904_Eladas.Name as `Name`, b904_Eladas.Color AS Color, SUM(b904_Eladas.QTY) AS Total_QTY
  FROM b904_Eladas
  GROUP BY NAME, Color) AS E
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT b904_Vasarlas.Name as `Name`, b904_Vasarlas.Color AS Color, SUM(b904_Vasarlas.QTY) AS Total_QTY
  FROM b904_Vasarlas
  GROUP BY NAME, Color) AS V
ON V.Name = E.Name AND V.Color = E.Color
UNION
SELECT 
E.Name AS EName
, V.Name AS VName
, COALESCE(E.Name ,v.Name) AS Name
, E.Color AS EColor
, V.Color AS VColor
, COALESCE(E.Color , V.Color) AS Color
, COALESCE(E.Total_QTY,0) AS EQTY
, COALESCE(V.Total_QTY, 0) AS VQTY
, COALESCE(V.Total_QTY,0) - COALESCE(E.Total_QTY, 0) AS NETQTY
FROM
  (SELECT b904_Eladas.Name as `Name`, b904_Eladas.Color AS Color, SUM(b904_Eladas.QTY) AS Total_QTY
  FROM b904_Eladas
  GROUP BY NAME, Color) AS E
RIGHT JOIN 
  (SELECT b904_Vasarlas.Name as `Name`, b904_Vasarlas.Color AS Color, SUM(b904_Vasarlas.QTY) AS Total_QTY
  FROM b904_Vasarlas
  GROUP BY NAME, Color) AS V
ON V.Name = E.Name AND V.Color = E.Color
ORDER BY 3,6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the sum from the second table.

```
SELECT v.PrintedFigure as Image, 
    v.ProductColor as Color, 
    SUM(v.QTY) - (
        SELECT SUM(e.QTY)
        FROM `b904_Eladas` e 
        WHERE e.PrintedFigure = v.PrintedFigure
          AND e.ProductColor  = v.ProductColor
    ) as QTY_diff 
FROM `b904_Vasarlas` v
GROUP BY v.PrintedFigure, v.ProductColor
ORDER by v.PrintedFigure, v.ProductColor
```